# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cannot find the xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, maven

I read several posts regarding this but still don't understand how to solve my issue. I am creating a *Spring Web Service* using this source as a starting point:
http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/01/03/spring-3-restful-web-services/

It has `src/main/java` folders and `src/main/webapp/`...

I want to add a rest client in `com.spring.client/RestClient.java`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/client-context.xml");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = (RestTemplate)ctx.getBean("restTemplate");

        addStudent(restTemplate);
    }
```

But when I try to run it, it cannot find the `client-context.xml` file no matter where I put it. I'tried `"client-context.xml"`, `"META-INF/client-context.xml"`, etc...

I've tried putting my `client-context.xml` in `src/main`, `src/main/webapp`, `src/main/webapp/META-INF`, `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`, ...

It seems weird. I looked around and found another *Spring REST* tutorial with a working client. In that project, the `src/main/webapp` folders have a blue "S" on top of it while my other project does it. It's just a regular looking folder.

Does that make a difference? How do I fix this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`src/main/resources/META-INF`. The classpath root is `WEB-INF/classes`, and `src/main/resources` goes there, together with `src/main/java`

Comment: OK. I create a folder in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes and put the client.xml in there and it seems to find it. Thanks.

Comment: the proper place is `src/main/resources` though.

Comment: OK. I put it in src/main/resources